# Umbraco lazyload.js:260: error on loading extended backoffice js files

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

i try to extend umbraco back office with a new section and the folder structure was like the attachment

App_Plugins/BackofficeApplication/backoffice/BackofficeTree/js/edit.controller.js

and then i decided to change the name of the folder and made different names and added the section again to the user privileges and i am sure i changed the name in the [Application] annotation and in [PluginController] and [Tree] annotation but lazy load try to load the javascript files from the old path and i tried also to change client dependency version but the problem still the same.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRmnp.png)

Answer (score 1):

Check that your application is in debug mode - Umbraco caches static files (such as your JS file) using a client dependency handler. Cached files are stored in `\App_Data\TEMP\ClientDependency` (which can be deleted if you need your site to run out of debug mode).

If your site is in debug mode, this cache will not be used.

---

To turn debug mode on, search for `debug` in your `web.config`. You should find a section like this:

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false" batch="false" targetFramework="4.5">
```

Set `debug` to `true`.

Comment: i changed client dependency version, removed cache from .net folder
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ , and also restated IIS because i am woking on local iis and the issue still exists. can you guid me how to make my application into debug mode

Comment: I added the debug mode instructions to the answer.

Comment: It's gonna be hard to debug this any further without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Most packages come with a `package.manifest` file which includes paths to all of the files which your package uses. Check that you have updated these paths with your new folder and file names.

The `package.manifest` should be in the route of your package folder in `App_Plugins`.